# Where do SED questions belong within SOFU?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question on SED, where does it belong? 
SU? 
SO?

Probably not SF.

Comment: This sed or some other sed? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed Who the cheeso calls it "SED"? That's loud. And crazy. They called me crazy but I killed them.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sozialistische_Einheitspartei_Deutschlands

Comment: sed's dead, baby, sed's dead.

Comment: It's not a bike, it's a chopper, baby

Answer (score 3):

I default to considering `sed` a language and expect most such questions to be better suited for Stack Overflow than Super User. But I am not dogmatic about it. In some contexts Server Fault might the best place.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're trying to do with it.  I could think of applicable situations for all 3 sites.

Answer (score 2):

Post it on SO, and make sure you frame it as a programming question.

Comment: Yes, include the word 'programmatically' in your question or title and it will be difficult to argue with.